# Should I use Buffer and UTF-8 in Node.js for sending data across the wire?

Tags: javascript, java, node.js, utf-8, character-encoding

I have a system with two process, one in Java and one in Node.js. The node.js process is a web front-end. It ingests data and sends it to a queue for process, where it is consumed by the Java process. The data is a string of user data collected from browser code, and I create a string of the data in Node.js using `JSON.stringify(data)`, and push it to kinesis, the aws version of kafka. The java process receives the raw bytes, creates a string object, and then parses the json.

My question is this: I am not sure what decoding I should instruct Java to use on the raw bytes. Right now, it "just works" with the default decoding, but I feel this is a bad idea, since the default decoding could be platform-dependent. Should I use `Buffer` on the Node.js side, and encode the string into UTF-8 before I push it to the queue? That way I could explicitly set UTF-8 as the decoding on the java side? Is this a best practice? Any advice much appreciated.

Comment: http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc4627.txt *"JSON text SHALL be encoded in Unicode. The default encoding is UTF-8."* There is kind of an implicit encoding, maybe some libraries will do that automatically when they see json. The encoding is still subject to standard content negotiation: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Content_negotiation

Comment: Hmm are the down votes because the question is not specific enough?

Comment: I don't know for sure but it's a bit fuzzy and has lots of opinionated pieces about  "should I" & "best practice" where nobody can really say yes or no. Your text formatting is also rather dense so the question looks kind of intimidating. - I'd try to test the limits / mess the encoding up and e.g. change the default in some parts and see if / where it breaks. And I guess defining and enforcing a fixed encoding isn't a bad idea if there is doubt.